# Received job offer, might get an F...is it a problem?

Tags: job-offer, student

OK so I received a job offer from a company in early February but won't start until June because I have to finish Bachelor's.

Essentially, there's a chance I might get an F in a class that I don't need to graduate, just taking to get to 12 credits. I have like a 3.44 GPA with 130ish credits so it shouldn't have any effect really on my GPA and I've gotten less than a B only three times (two C+s and a C, all two plus years ago).

Firstly, would my employer even bother to ask for a transcript (its a software engineering job) and secondly how much would they care about the F? Is it a terminatable offense?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Is the offer in writing, or is it just a verbal offer? Is the offer contingent on anything (is there a clause that says the offer can be revoked for certain, or any, reason)? Adding that information may help people answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused about the close votes here.  This question is on topic and answerable.

Comment: Not sure about your school, but are you sure that you will receive the credits for a failed class?

Comment: @Chad - How are we suppose to know if the employeer cares about an F on the transcript of an employee.  We can't read minds, the author should as their employeer this question, the employeer could care if it was in a subject they specialized and the author was hired because of the class.

Comment: @jmac it's written and there's a clause that says that the offer can be revoked for any reason by either party.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you answered this yourself.  You said:

> I received a job offer from a company in early February but won't
>   start until June because I have to finish Bachelor's.

...and (emphasis mine):

> I might get an F **in a class that I don't need to graduate**

So what you need is your degree, not a passing mark in every single course that you registered for.

Your employer (like most employers) only really cares that you possess (or receive) the degree you advertised.  It's extremely unlikely that they're interested in your specific marks in each course that you took.  At most, they might care about your GPA (and generally that would only be during the screening/interview/pre-hire phase).

Moreover, I don't see how your employer would find out that you've failed the course, unless you volunteer the info.  Your school won't hand them an academic transcript, and I doubt they'd ask you for one (I've personally never been asked for one).  Your degree proves that you graduated, and that's likely all they care about.

I'd suggest not bringing the matter up at all, unless the offer you received is specifically contingent upon you passing all of your current courses (which it doesn't sound like it was).

There should be no problem with the failed course unless you manufacture one by trying too hard to be preemptive.  Most of the time 'wait and see' works better than panicking.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt that receiving an F is a cause for termination.  However, no one here can answer because it is completely based on the policies of your employer.

One path is to talk to the HR department to see what they say.  You should be aware that anything you say to HR may get back to the manager.

Another path is to just ignore it.  If failing this particular class will have no impact on your ability to get your degree then I wouldn't sweat it.  It's a rare case when the grades you receive in a particular class are looked at.  Usually all an employer cares about is that you did in fact receive your bachelors.

Answer (score 1):

> Essentially, there's a chance I might get an F in a class that I don't
>   need to graduate…

I have 100% no idea what field you are in, but I have never ever heard of someone ditched from a gig because their GPA was low. Let alone for a class they don’t need to graduate.

The thing about GPAs is they get you in the door. That’s it. Once you are there, you have to prove your worth. So if they have agreed to hire you, you’re done. Don’t worry about the rest.